# handle exception from vendor script

Tags: javascript, error-handling

What are the best practices to handle exceptions from vendor scripts to avoid app crashes?

we can abstract it in a utility func like below -

```
function utilityFn() {
  try {
    vendor();
  } catch (err) {
    //handle error
  }
}
```

Is there any better way to do these things?

Comment: Depends on what `vendor` is actually doing and how your app can "crash"

Comment: @Bergi lets say its a tracker function that is not part of core logic. I don't want my app to crash due to any exception for this

Comment: And "app" refers to a web app (frontend)? A backend? A desktop app? A mobile app? Where in the app's code are you calling `vendor()`?

Comment: @Bergi sorry. Missed specifying that. Its frontend web app.